# POST redirections using Javascript

Tags: html, forms, redirect, post

If you want to redirect the user of your website to a certain URL, you might want to use the `window.location.replace('/resource')` function. The problem is that it does only GET requests to the given URL.

If you want to use another verb (like POST), you may want to use a form like that:

```
<form method="POST" action="/resource">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But again there is a problem, it requires the user to click on the submit button to actually start the redirect.

How should I do to redirect the user of my website to a POST route without needing him to click on the submit button of a form?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function submit() {
  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
}
```

```html
<!-- Place this button anywhere you want in the body (it can even be in a form) -->
<button type="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

<!-- Place this form outside of another form -->
<form action="/resource" method="POST" id="myForm"></form>
```